# how to use SQL connection string class in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

i want to create a class which maintain sql connection instead of creating sql connection everytime.

**models.py**
 
in models.py i declare sql connection in sqlconn method whenever i call this i want to establish sql connection in views.py

```
from django.db import models
import pyodbc

def sqlconn(request):
    constr = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhose;DATABASE=testdb;UID=user;PWD=password"
    conn = pyodbc.connect(constr)
    return conn
```

**Views.py**
in this views.py i'm retrieving employee data from database instead of writing sqlconnection string in every views.py method. I want to call sqlconn method from models and i want to do further process like
**getdata, insertdata, deletedata, updatedate**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import sqlconn
import pyodbc


    def getEmpData(request):
        conn = sqlconn
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        #cursor.execute("select * from Employee")
        cursor.execute("exec sp_demotable")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        return render(request, 'getempdata.html', {'result':result})
```

i tried above code but its not working its showing error, any help thanks in advance

---

**Note:**
what is the best practices for python any articles are videos tutorials provide its great help for me, because i'm new to python but i've good knowledge in .NET Programming

---

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use SQLAchemy library as ORM for project.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you for you reply, but it is possible with out SQLAchemy library if yes how